# Selenium won't find link by partial link text

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following Python code fragment (the full thing is too long):

```
menu=driver.find_element_by_class_name("dtList")
for vertical_element in verticallist:
    menu.find_element_by_partial_link_text(vertical_element).click()
```

This is what `print vertical_element` looks like (data type is `unicode`):

```
"Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Food"
```

Below is what `print menu.get_attribute('innerHTML')` gets me:

```
<ul><li style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);" node="{&quot;code&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Series&quot;,&quot;sort&quot;:&quot;4&quot;}">Series</li><li style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);" title="Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Food" code="A01010601" node="{&quot;code&quot;:&quot;A01010601&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Food&quot;,&quot;sort&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}">Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Food</li><li style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);" title="Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Grain" code="A01010602" node="{&quot;code&quot;:&quot;A01010602&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Grain&quot;,&quot;sort&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}">Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Grain</li><li style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);" title="Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Meat, _Poultry and Processed Products" code="A01010603" node="{&quot;code&quot;:&quot;A01010603&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Meat, _Poultry and Processed Products&quot;,&quot;sort&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}">Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Meat, _Poultry and Processed Products</li><li style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);" title="Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Eggs" code="A01010604" node="{&quot;code&quot;:&quot;A01010604&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Eggs&quot;,&quot;sort&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}">Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Eggs</li><li style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);" title="Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Aquatic _Products" code="A01010605" node="{&quot;code&quot;:&quot;A01010605&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Aquatic _Products&quot;,&quot;sort&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}">Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Aquatic _Products</li><li style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);" title="Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Fresh _Vegetables" code="A01010606" node="{&quot;code&quot;:&quot;A01010606&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Fresh _Vegetables&quot;,&quot;sort&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}">Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Fresh _Vegetables</li><li style="border-bottom: medium none;" title="Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Fresh _Fruits" code="A01010607" node="{&quot;code&quot;:&quot;A01010607&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Fresh _Fruits&quot;,&quot;sort&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}">Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Fresh _Fruits</li></ul>
```

Clearly there is a link in there with `"Consumer Price Indices (preceding month=100), Food"` in it, and yet I get an `"unable to locate element"` error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Clearly there is a link in there` Where? I don't see any `<a>` tags whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry... In my html ignorance, I had mistaken <li> for a link element analogous to <a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on what @That1Guy is pointing out, there are no links, `a` elements, in the menu you've presented, but "by partial link text" locator would only check the `a` element's text.

Instead, locate the `li` element by text:

```
menu.find_element_by_xpath(".//li[. = '%s']" % vertical_element).click()
```